# Polymorphic classes as template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism

I have polymorphic classes that take another polymorphic classes as template arguments.

I would like to do something like this:

```cpp
class A{ public: virtual ~A() = default; };

class B : public A{};
class C : public A{};


template<typename A>
class X{ public: virtual ~X() = default; };

class Y : public X<B>{};
class Z : public X<C>{};


int main(void)
{
    X<A> *test = new Y();
    (void)test;

    return 0;
}
```

but I obtain this error:

```
error: cannot convert 'Y*' to 'X<A>*' in initialization
X<A> *test = new Y();
```

The goal is to have some containers of X instances:

```cpp
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<X<A>>> data;
data.push_back( std::make_unique<Y>() );
data.push_back( std::make_unique<Z>() );
```

How can I do proceed ?

Comment: There is no relationship between `X<A>` and `X<B>`, even if `A` and `B` are related.

Comment: Create a superclass above `X` and use it instead of `X<A>` (you could use a template specialization)? What's the purpose of having `X` templated here? Looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Comment: Why are you messing around with operator `new`? What's the point of the pointers?

Comment: C# provides contravariance in its generics implementation but C++ does not provide the same in C++.

Comment: @keith Covariance*?

Comment: @Quentin, sigh, yes :-)